# group rows based on sum of values in a column in pandas / numpy

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have table as in below

[image]

I need to add date column with values based on sum of values in consequtive rows. date increments or stays same on the rows based on the sum of values is less than or equal to max value.

[image]

my data is in excel.

wondering how i can achieve this in python using pandas or numpy or any other lib.

any pointers?

thanks

looking for pointers

Comment: Pls copy the data/Table as a text and paste it here instead of screenshots

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one option with a combo [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas)/[numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy) :

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

MAX = df["value"].max()
​
arr = df["value"].mask(df["value"].eq(MAX), other=0).to_numpy(copy=True)
cs_func = np.frompyfunc(lambda a,b: a+b if a < MAX+1 else b, 2, 1)
​
ser = pd.Series(cs_func.accumulate(arr))
​
offset = (ser.eq(df["value"]) | ser.gt(MAX)).cumsum()
​
df["date"] = (pd.Timestamp.today() + pd.to_timedelta(offset, unit="D")).dt.strftime("%m/%d/%y")
​
```

Output :

```
print(df)

  rowid  value      date
0     a      8  04/14/23
1     b      1  04/15/23
2     v      2  04/15/23
3     d      4  04/15/23
4     e      3  04/16/23
5     f      6  04/17/23
6     g      2  04/17/23
```

*Intermediates :*

```
  rowid  value  arr ser  offset      date
0     a      8    0   0       0  04/14/23
1     b      1    1   1       1  04/15/23
2     v      2    2   3       1  04/15/23
3     d      4    4   7       1  04/15/23
4     e      3    3  10       2  04/16/23
5     f      6    6   6       3  04/17/23
6     g      2    2   8       3  04/17/23
```

Answer (score 1):

So basically you have the following inputs:

```py
x = [8, 1, 2, 4, 3, 6, 2]
threshold = 8
```

And want to create groups, which might be encoded as follows:

```py
expected = [0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3]
```

You can use the following function, which might not be optimized (plain for loop):

```py
def groupby_moving_sum_threshold(x, threshold):
    groups = []
    group_idx, total = 0, 0
    for n in x:
        total += n
        if total > threshold:
            group_idx += 1
            total = n
        groups.append(group_idx)
    return groups
```

It provides the good result:

```py
assert groupby_moving_sum_threshold(x, threshold) == expected
```

If the `x` input is a column of a pandas dataframe, use it to create a new column `group`.

Based on that new column you'll be able to achieve what you want:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"rowid": list("abcdefg"), "value": x})

df["group"] = groupby_moving_sum_threshold(df["value"], threshold)
df["date"] = ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take advantage of pandas apply method.

This is a trivial example where date is an integer but could fairly easy be modified to your desired date format.

````
df = pd.DataFrame([{"row_id": 'a', "value": 2}, {"row_id": 'b', "value": 6}, {"row_id": 'c', "value": 2}, {"row_id": 'c', "value": 7},  {"row_id": 'c', "value": 3}])
sum = 0
START_DATE = 1
date = START_DATE  # date at fist row

def func(row):
    global sum
    global date
    sum += row.value
    if row.name == 0:  # skip first row
        return START_DATE

    if sum >= 8:  # reset threshold increase date
        sum = 0 
        date += 1
    return date

df["date"] = START_DATE  # initialize to START_DATE
df["date"] = df.apply(func, axis=1)  # apply function row-wise

print(df.to_string())```
````

| index | row_id | value | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | a | 2 | 1 |
| 1 | b | 6 | 2 |
| 2 | c | 2 | 2 |
| 3 | c | 7 | 3 |
| 4 | c | 3 | 3 |

Comment: Be aware, that by declaring the variable `sum` you will overwrite the `sum()` fucntion